# Windows Mobile - Settings

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, settings, system-setting

I need to programtically make settings for all items that are shown in **Settings menu** of windows mobile. This includes **Personal, System and Connection tabs** on setttings screen. Is there any API that provices access to all settings items? I am using .NET CF 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these settings should be saved in Windows Registry. You can use [CERegSpy](http://www.forwardlab.com/ceregspy.htm) to monitor Registry changes and programmatically apply them in your .NET CF application. The following code snippet may help:

```
using using Microsoft.Win32;
Registry.SetValue(`PATH`, `KEY_NAME`, `VALUE`);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the path used to store this settings? I don't need to show/hide this settings. I need to change it. E.g. I should be able to set ring tone, button settings, regional settings, power setting etc.

Comment: You can use CERegSpy to monitor your registry and find the path. Also you can use an application called `CeRegEditor` to take a snapshot from your registry and change the settings you want, then take another snapshot and compare it with the previous one to find the keys and values.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same thing as you suggested.

Comment: Is there any documentation on Registry from where I can see all Registry keys and what they mean?

Comment: You can find it on Windows Mobile communities like http://www.xda-developers.com, http://www.modaco.com, http://www.ppcgeeks.com, ...